# How to get DataSource or Connection from JPA2 EntityManager in Java EE 6

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, java-ee-6

I have a working application where I use Java EE 6 with EclipseLink for persistence and a PostgreSQL database.

For the User-Registration I want to set the password in PostgreSQL to:

```
... password = crypt('inputPassword',gen_salt('bf')) ...
```

As I cant use DigestUtils for this, I have to insert the user manually into the DB.
To keep my application configurable I do not want to query the DataSource with an
`InitialContextInstance.lookup(dataSource)` but to extract it (or the Connection) somehow from the EntityManager
like:

```
DataSource ds = entityManagerInstance.someFunctionThatReturnsADataSourceOrConnection();
```

Or would it be possible to use createNativeQuery or something similar in conjuntion
with a prepared statement to protect against injections?

Comment: If you use a datasource for your JPA configuration, you should be able  to get access to it using a `@Resource(name="myDb") DataSource myDB`. Isn't so? And I think you can define parametirized queries with JPA as well.

Comment: yes, that might work, but I still have to know the name. I want to get the configured default DataSource for an injected EntityManager.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

sometimes it just takes another run in google:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
...
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

as described in the [Eclipse Link Documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager)

Comment: Is that part of the standard. It seems to be specific to Eclipselink

Comment: is there  a way to get the password from this connection

Comment: good answer working on JPA + JTA (Java SDK 8u31) + WebSphere 8.5.5

Answer (score 6):

In response to "Archimedes Trajano" comment to the accepted answer, does the accepted answer work for other than Eclipselink? The answer is no for at least Hibernate.

I got the following error when I tried the accepted answer for hibernate:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface java.sql.Connection; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface java.sql.Connection
     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418) ~[spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

A combination of answers from the following stackoverflow questions allowed me to come up with a solution that works for Hibernate.

[Get hold of a JDBC Connection object from a Stateless Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707115/get-hold-of-a-jdbc-connection-object-from-a-stateless-bean)

[Hibernate get Connection object for JasperRunManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218655/hibernate-get-connection-object-for-jasperrunmanager)

Here is my solution:

```
    Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    hibernateSession.doWork(new org.hibernate.jdbc.Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            // do whatever you need to do with the connection
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of code that works with Hibernate 4, based on dulon's answer

```
Connection getConnection() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        MyWork myWork = new MyWork();
        session.doWork(myWork);
        return myWork.getConnection();
}


private static class MyWork implements Work {

    Connection conn;

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {
        this.conn = arg0;
    }

    Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

}
```