# EJB Container Managed Transaction with JDBC Result Set and MDB

Tags: java, jdbc, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean

I have a Stateless session bean. In the following method I loop the list to insert each of user into the table 'user'.

```
void saveUserList(List<User> users) {
  try {
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;

    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER_LIST);

      for (User user : users) {
        ps.setString(1, user.getName);

        if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {
          sendJMSMessage();
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    // catch error!!
  } finally {
    closeResource(conn);
  }
}
```

Upon each successful insert, the trigger flag is sent to an MDB. Here is the sendJMSMessage method...

```
void sendJMSMessage() {
  conn = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
  qsession = conn.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  QueueSender sender = qsession.createSender(queue);
  conn.start();

  TextMessage flag = qsession.createTextMessage("triggerFlag");
  flag.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
  sender.send(flag);
}
```

Then it will invoke the MDB's onMessage method. Here, in the onMessage, I want to fetch all users from the table 'user', including the last inserted user (which may be uncommitted yet when the loop is still iterating the list). The fetch process happened in another stateless EJB that is invoked by the onMessage. I expected the record is fetched there. But the result sets got nothing.

```
void onMessage(Message message) {
  TextMessage obj = (TextMessage) message;

  if (obj.getText.equals("triggerFlag")) {
    ArrayList<User> users = someBean.getUsers();
    // Do something with them, as well as the new user.
  }
}
```

With the current code, I usually need to re-execute the saveUserList() with passing a different list in order to get the expected result. What I wanted to know is:

1. Is it possible to do that?
2. When is the first insert transaction get commited?
3. Can MDB reads the uncommited changes in a table?
4. What is the proper way to read the table changes from MDB that was triggered by an EJB?
5. Is there alternatives method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. It really depends on how you got the connection (or DataSource). If you unwrapped it from an injected `EntityManager`, then the transaction is automatically committed when your (first entered) EJB method returns (this is so by default, i.e if nothing otherwise annotated!)
3. Yes, if the MDB's connection uses the lowest transaction isolation level "READ_UNCOMMITTED". This is not trivial to implement and again depends on how you get the connection.
4. (&5)Probably the cleanest way to solve your problem is to control the transaction manually (use an injected `UserTransaction`, instead of Container Managed Transactions (CMT)). Only you are done if the entire list of users (not for every user as you do now) and after you have committed the transaction (programtically with `UserTransaction`), you are 100% that your second stateless bean will see all your users. In this case you should sent the message only once.

Comment: "If you unwrapped it from an injected EntityManager". What is it mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994226/how-to-get-datasource-or-connection-from-jpa2-entitymanager-in-java-ee-6

Comment: In my case, I just looking up the datasource JNDI with InitialContext. What if I create a new transaction in the onMessage method (with UserTransaction.begin())? Will the previous transaction (that happens in the first EJB) gets committed?

Comment: I am not sure what the behavior of a directly-managed JDNI connection is. What I described in my answer is when unwrapping it from the `EntityManager`.

Comment: @Bogie did you succeed?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry to accidentally accepted your answer. I was on mobile yesterday. So, I've been tried to send the JMS message after the first closeResource(conn) in the finally block (which I think the transaction is commited when the connection closed). But I didn't test it yet.
For me, the transaction process seems hard to be learnt. I think there was a misconception about it.

Comment: You should open two consoles to your DB, and play a bit to see how it works. Also if your database can log all queries (like MySQL), you could also check directly what queries are sent to it.

Comment: Finally, I've been succeed by following this article [link](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/09/get-current-jta-transaction-status-from-cmt-ejb/). It gave me an idea to use the `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` and use the `registerInterposedSynchronization` to register a synchronization callback that will do the rest, send the JMS message. It will send the message only if the transaction state is committed.