# How can I update a BLOB from an InputStream via an EntityManager?

Tags: jpa, streaming, blob

I have a table:

```
mysql> desc documents;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| item_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| doctype | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| name    | varchar(128) | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| descr   | text         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| created | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| changed | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| doc     | longblob     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Which I have mapped as an `Entity` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents", schema = "office_db")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    ...,
    @NamedQuery(name = "Documents.updateDocById", query = "UPDATE Documents d SET d.doc = :document WHERE d.id = :id")
})
public class Documents implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "name", length = 128)
    private String name;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "descr", length = 65535)
    private String descr;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "doc")
    private byte[] doc;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "changed")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date changed;
    ...
}
```

And I want to update the LONGBLOB DOC column with the contents of a file. To that end, I have acquired an `InputStream` and want to associate it with my `NamedQuery` - I have naively tried the following, expecting it to fail (which it does, of course):

```
public String updateDocument(Integer id,InputStream is){
    String msg="";
    try{
        Query stmt=em.createNamedQuery("Documents.updateDocById")
                .setParameter("document",is);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    ...
}
```

If I had used a `PreparedStatement`, I could have used the `setBinaryStream` method, but is that really the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to answer my own question: It seems that JPA does not support streaming, at least not until JPA 2.2 according to [What’s new in JPA 2.2 – Stream the result of a Query execution | Vlad Mihalcea's Blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/) - and it looks like it is only for streaming the results of a query, not for updating a BLOB, which is what I was looking for.

It looks like it is back to using a `PreparedStatement` and `setBinaryStream()`. I havent tried it yet, but based on [How to get DataSource or Connection from JPA2 EntityManager in Java EE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994226/how-to-get-datasource-or-connection-from-jpa2-entitymanager-in-java-ee-6), my strategy will be to:

- Start a transaction.
- Extract the connection from the `EntityManager`.
- Create a `PreparedStatement`.
- ...
- Commit or rollback the transaction.

I think it is a bit nasty, but there you are.